# Set background image on grid in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem: I want to set the image of my grid through code behind.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Did you forget the [Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx) Property. The brush should be an ImageBrush whose ImageSource could be set to your image path.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/path/to/image.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <...>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can u tell me the exact syntax for this

Comment: @SHASHANK: The syntax would be something like this: `<Grid Background="{StaticResource yourBrush}" />`

Answer (score 81):

All of this can easily be acheived in the xaml by adding the following code in the grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>  
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProject;component/Images/bg.png"/>     
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Left for you to do, is adding a folder to the solution called 'Images' and adding an existing file to your new 'Images' folder, in this case called 'bg.png'

Comment: This is the best answer @Shashank

Comment: The question was to set the image in code behind.

Answer (score 33):

I have my images in a separate class library ("MyClassLibrary") and they are placed in the folder "Images". In the example I used "myImage.jpg" as the background image.

```
  ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
  Image image = new Image();
  image.Source = new BitmapImage(
      new Uri(
         "pack://application:,,,/MyClassLibrary;component/Images/myImage.jpg"));
  myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
  Grid grid = new Grid();
  grid.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: There's no point creating that `Image` since you're not using it for anything. You can just set the `ImageSource` on the `ImageBrush` directly.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid path problem, you can simply try this, just keep background image in images folder and add this code

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="..\Images\background.jpg"
                AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```