# WPF textured buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, textures

I want to create a button in a 2D UI (in this case, it's the selection window that opens as soon as I start my application) which has got a wooden panel as background. This image should be tiled, and not stretched to fit the entire button.

Also, I want that the background image doesn't disappear when the cursor is moved over the button.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: [How to set background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100837/how-to-set-background-image-on-grid-in-wpf-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

The XAML code should be something like:

```
<Button>
<Button.Content>
<Grid height="40" width="40"> <!--you can adjust the height and wdith  according to your preferences-->
<Image Source="your_path_to_image" />
</Grid>
<Button.Content>
</Button>
```

The image should not dissapear when you press the button, but if so, use the events cicked and hover and threat them. If you don't succeed with this post a comment and I will write and post a working sample for you :)