# How to layout Xaml on top of a PNG asset

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I've been designing my app in Adobe Xd and it exports to either PNG or PDF or SVG there no Xaml! so how i would use the image in VS to have a responsive UI (buttons and other controls)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are writing a WPF or Silverlight app and want to design an app over your image (and not leverage the controls created in Adobe XD), then I'd [set your image as the background to a parent grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100837/how-to-set-background-image-on-grid-in-wpf-using-c-sharp) with the same grid dimensions that you used in Adobe XD, then recreate your controls in XAML following your previous grid layout.

```
    <Grid  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="22"  Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyImage.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
```