# Change background wpf c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change the background of my wpf app in visual studio by clicking on a button. I'd like it to change to a new image in a folder every time the button is clicked. Is there any way to implement this?

I'm fairly new to c# and haven't been able to find anything online to help.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the attribute `background`

Comment: ps.: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100837/set-background-image-on-grid-in-wpf-using-c-sharp) is a link about how to change background to an image. If you run into specific problems feel free to post those here.

Comment: Mix that code with your onclick event for the button and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: I have set my background now via the xaml but i can't find the syntax to change it once i'm in my xaml.cs i also want to add a variable to my path so that everytime the button is pressed the variable goes 1 up and it would use the next image in my folder